# How to export Preferences in Visual Studio v.8.x for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

VS on Windows, of course, has an Export / Import feature for your Settings, so they can be easily re-installed on new machines or shared with other team members.

Does VS for Mac have the same functionality? I can't find it.

As an alternative, where or what file are my Preference changes saved to? I searched in my $HOME/Library folders, but couldn't find anything obviously relevant.

I'm using VS for Mac 8.4.1.

This question was originally asked [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-export-vs-mac-preferences/182137) by Scott Cadillac.
This post got an interesting response by Matt Ward about were the preferences are stored: [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-export-vs-mac-preferences/182137#T-N182292)

The accepted answer shows here the custom keybindings are stored

Comment: This question seems to be heavily based on, if not copied outright from, [this one on the VS Developer Community forums](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/182137/how-to-export-vs-mac-preferences.html). If you're looking for an updated answer, that's fine, but please be sure to [give credit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) to the person who originally wrote the question, as you should do when you borrow *anyone's* work. If by some chance you haven't already seen that, perhaps the answers there will be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/VisualStudio`

[image: Preference files in file system]

It seems that Visual Studio uses the major versions like `7.0` and `8.0` to store the settings like shown in the screenshot. Minor versions like `8.2`, `8.3` etc. only contain json files for the team memberships.